Is creation a "transmutation of the divine reality"?
Adin Steinsaltz in his book The Thirteen Petalled Rose says,

His creation being not the act of forming something out of nothing but the act of revelation.  Creation is an emanation from the divine light; its secret is not the coming into existence of something new but the transmutation of the divine reality into something defined and limited" (pg 26).

How can creation be an emanation from the divine light because isn't the divine light itself created?  Also God the creator cannot change, so something new has to come into existence at some point. I suspect this isn't the best explanation ever.
